# Graylog cannot start inputs. Getting Error in graylog web

Tags: java, input, graylog

If I try to create any type of inputs on my new Graylog server I'm getting a java dump.  Currently running on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with Java 1.8, MongoDB and Elasticsearch.  There's no errors in the mongodb, graylog server, or elasticsearch logs.  The elasticsearch cluster status is green.

No matter which input I select, I'm getting an error:

> This exception has been logged with id 6p63dbml7.

In the  /var/log/graylog-web/web.log, I'm seeing these errors:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class play.data.validation.Validation
>           at play.data.Form.bind(Form.java:324) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-java_2.10--2.3.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
>           at play.data.Form.bindFromRequest(Form.java:221) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-java_2.10--2.3.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
>           at controllers.InputsController.launch(InputsController.java:252) ~[graylog-web-interface.graylog-web-interface-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
>           at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$33$$anonfun$apply$533.apply(routes_routing.scala:1853) ~[graylog-web-interface.graylog-web-interface-1.2.2.jar:na]
>           at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$33$$anonfun$apply$533.apply(routes_routing.scala:1853) ~[graylog-web-interface.graylog-web-interface-1.2.2.jar:na]
>           at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(Router.scala:264) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
>           at play.core.Router$HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$15$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:255) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
>           at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:55) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
>           at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:67) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
>           at play.mvc.Security$AuthenticatedAction.call(Security.java:44) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
>           ... 33 common frames omitted

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

AJ

Comment: How did you install Graylog? Did you try to compile it yourself? This looks like you are missing a library or having some other classpath issue.

Comment: I followed the online guide.  I'm going to rebuild as that was just a test server anyway.